# How can I hide directories or files without changing their names?

Tags: gui, directory, hidden-files

The OCD in me wants directories I do not like the name of to be hidden since I do not interact with them directly.

How can I hide directories without using the dot notation?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Assuming you only care about hiding the files from showing up in nautilus, there is a [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=311010) on the GNOME Bugzilla about this. However, currently, that bug has not been resolved.

There is another way to hide files from appearing in nautilus. If you create a file called `.hidden` inside of a directory, any filename listed in the file will not be displayed.

For example, below is a .hidden file that I created. This file will hide any files or folders named `b` or `e` located in the same directory as the .hidden file.

[image: Example .hidden File]

Below is a screenshot of the folder that contains the .hidden file. Note that you only see three files: `a`, `c`, and `f`. You do not see the .hidden file due to the '.' at the beginning of its name.
[image: Example Folder]

The screenshot below is of the same folder as before. However, this time, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to cause nautilus to display hidden files and folders. Notice how there are several additional files that show up. You now see several files that were previously hidden due to having names that began with a '.'. There are also now files called 'b' and 'e', which although not having names beginning with a '.', were hidden due to being listed in the .hidden file.

[image: Example Folders With Hidden Files Visible]

Files mentioned in the .hidden file will only be hidden in nautilus. Tools like `ls` will still display them. The .hidden file is also not recursive. It only affects files in the same directory as the .hidden file is in.

Some people on the forum have gone ahead and created scripts for nautilus that make it easier to add files to the .hidden file. The [first script](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=4985689&postcount=5) includes a nice explanation about how to install and use the scripts, but the [second script](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=4986335&postcount=6) is a bit cleaner and shorter. Feel free to use either script to make your life a bit easier.

Comment: +1. Just a note, IF you think you have to add `'` for file or folder name which contains ` ` space, it is not. Simply add the file or folder name

Answer (score 13):

Unix and Linux only supports hiding folders that being with a `.`.

If you really want to get them out of the way, but want them to not have `.`s, put them all in a `.hidden` in the same directory as the file or folder you want to hide. `.hidden` will not be exposed by the file manager, and your files will not have a name change.

Comment: i would so like to keep them in the same place :)

Comment: this solution will keep them in their same place.  .hidden doesn't even have to be in your home folder if you don't want it to be.  I usually use it on removable drives that have config files I don't want to see.

Comment: @jumpnett is correct, place .hidden in the same location as the files you want to hide, and add the file/directory names in the .hidden file, one per line. Works great!

Answer (score 4):

From the command line you could try something like this in your `.bash_aliases` file:

```
lsh() {
    [ -s .hidden ] && echo "lsh: hiding $(wc -l .hidden) patterns" && ls $@ | grep -v -F "$(cat .hidden)";
    [ ! -f .hidden ] && ls $@
}
```

This adds a new command `lsh` that behaves like `ls`, but hides files listed in a `.hidden` directory. (It also is missing some of its features like  colorized output and column listings.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide files, you are only left with renaming them with a preceding `.`, as is *NIX convention. Sorry, but that's it.

However, if you would like to hide the **content** of the files/directories, you can do so with file permissions.

So say you have a bunch of files in a folder called `secret_stash`, you could change it so that only you (the owner) have `r-x` (read, execute) and everyone else has nothing `---` (no access). Since `r-x` is the minimum perms needed to view a directory (read to access its contents and execute to be able to see them), anything inside of that folder is effectively hidden from everyone but `root`.

**NOTE**: I'm running this demo as `root`, and trying to access the folder as `myuser`

To do this you run `chmod 700 dirname` (700 means `rwx------`):

```
% mkdir secret_stash
% chmod 700 secret_stash
```

And here it is:

```
% whoami
root
% ls -ld secret_stash
drwx------ 2 root root 4.0K 2010-08-12 07:59 secret_stash/
% ls secret_stash  
./  ../  secret.txt
% cat secret_stash/secret.txt 
TOP SECRET DATA
```

Now and if I try to access it from `myuser`, attempts to access the folder or its contents fail:

```
% whoami
myuser
% ls -ld secret_stash
drwx------ 2 root root 4.0K 2010-08-12 07:59 secret_stash/
% ls secret_stash 
ls: cannot open directory secret_stash: Permission denied
% cat secret_stash/secret.txt
cat: secret_stash/secret.txt: Permission denied
```

And now I've said the word "secret" so many times it's lost all meaning!!

Comment: You can make it really hidden with `chmod -R 000 secret_stash` then no one will be able to read it!

Comment: @Marco Ceppi - ULTIMATE SECRECY!

Comment: Of course this is more "Security" than it is "Obscurity" - which is what the OP was looking for I think ;)

Comment: @MarcoCeppi: chmod 000 will hide the file from even the owner of the file, except the root, which can always bypass 000. However, the owner of the file can still change the permission of the file to read it, so you need to also change the ownership of the file to root to make the 000 permission really meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

1st off: if you want to hide a file from anyone: install a [linux intrusion detection system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Intrusion_Detection_System). ([Snort](https://www.snort.org/) is an example) You can even hide a file from "root" but "root" will also be able to revert those setting.

---

But it might be easier to just set the permissions of the directory that holds the file to "root". Example:

```
 $ sudo su
 # mkdir tmp/
 # touch tmp/1
 # chown root:root tmp
 # chmod 000 tmp  
 # ls -l
total 4
d--------- 2 root root 4096 2015-08-07 06:36 tmp  
 # exit
exit
 $ ls
tmp
 $ cd tmp/
bash: cd: tmp/: Permission denied
```

And the file `1` is effectively hidden from view.

Directory will be visible; file will not be visible. 
Mind though: "root" will ALWAYS have access to any file.

---

Together with the `chattr` you can even make the file immutable.

```
sudo su    
chattr + i {file}
```

and even "root" can not alter the file -unless- the `chattr` is reverted (and yes "root" can do that).

> Any Keyboard Shortcut for that?

No, this is something you need to do manually.

Answer (score 0):

There's also an extension for Nautilus called *nautilus-hide* that will allow you to hide any file or folder with a simple right-click on them.

To install this extension :
`sudo apt-get install nautilus-hide` in a terminal,
or search for "nautilus hide" in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Don't forget to quit Nautilus after installation : <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `nautilus -q`.