# Is it possible to hide folders?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, nautilus-elementary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I hide folders without changing their names?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2034/how-can-i-hide-folders-without-changing-their-names)

I want to hide some folders that I don't really want to hide all those folders that I don't use. Since system is using them I can't really rename them to add `.` in front of them. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For hiding things in Nautilus (and maybe other graphical browsers) when you can't rename, you can create a file called `.hidden` in the current directory and list the paths you don't want shown.

For example if I have a direcory with subdirectories `{a..f}` and a `.hidden` containing:

```
b
c
```

`ls -l` shows everything still:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 oli oli 4096 2011-06-29 23:02 a
drwxr-xr-x 2 oli oli 4096 2011-06-29 23:02 b
drwxr-xr-x 2 oli oli 4096 2011-06-29 23:02 c
drwxr-xr-x 2 oli oli 4096 2011-06-29 23:02 d
drwxr-xr-x 2 oli oli 4096 2011-06-29 23:02 e
drwxr-xr-x 2 oli oli 4096 2011-06-29 23:02 f
```

But Nautilus only shows:

[image]

Comment: I found a problem for myself. I cannot create .hidden file inside root directory because it is saying that I don't have permission, although I am logged as admin. What can I do?

Comment: Ah, I did some research and did it in terminal, thanks for your help!