# How can I make a hidden file/folder?

Tags: 11.10, command-line, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I hide directories without changing their names?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2034/how-can-i-hide-directories-without-changing-their-names)

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and I want to make a file hidden.

How do I make for example a *.docx* file or a directory hidden?

*Please put a way to do it **with** and **without** the terminal?*

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Hiding files and directories in Linux is very simple. All you have to do is append a period at the beginning of the name of the file/directory.

**With terminal:**

```
mv filename .filename
```

(This command also works with directories)

*Some additional information about the `mv` command; if the second argument is a directory, the first argument will be moved into that directory, rather than being renamed to it (regardless of whether the first argument was a file or a directory). If the first argument is a directory and the second is a file, you will get an error.* **If both the first and the second arguments are existing files, the second will be overwritten without prompting you!** *If you wish to be prompted before overwriting, add `-i` to the command before either argument*

To view hidden files and directories in a terminal, use `ls -a`.

**Without terminal:**

Click on the file, press the <kbd>F2</kbd> key and add a period at the beginning of the name. To view hidden files and directories in Nautilus (Ubuntu's default file explorer), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. The same keys will also re-hide revealed files.

Comment: If the file have an extension, adding a "~" at the end of the extension name also works.

Comment: Also for 16.04 you need to refresh the display to update the hidden state. Pressing ctrl-H twice will do.

Answer (score 7):

To make a file or folder hidden, rename it to begin with a dot, for example, `.file.docx`.

To see the hidden files in Nautilus, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, and in the terminal, use `ls -a`.

Answer (score 2):

You just put a dot at the beginning of a folder or a file. 
Nautilus has the option to show this files.