# How to hide folder

Tags: directory, hidden-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I hide directories without changing their names?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2034/how-can-i-hide-directories-without-changing-their-names)

How can I hide a folder and only see it when Ctrl+H is pressed?
I have checked in Properties and couldn't find it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/107940/39372

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple. Just put a dot before the folder name you want to hide.

```
.folder
```

Comment: Adding a dot can break things. Imagine doing that with the Desktop directory in home. See the 1st link in comments: it is better to create a .hidden file and add your directory in that file.

Comment: The `.hidden` file is a bit too complicated for average users.  The 'put a dot before' answer is IMHO better.

Comment: ctrl+h sho hidden file and hide the .folder