# When I create a folder in ~/ starting with a period, where is is located?

Tags: directory

I'm told to make a folder and put a file into it, and the instructions read like this:

```
~/.foldername
```

So `foldername` is the folder I'm creating and the directory that they tell me to place it in is `~/`.

Please help. I searched through all the folders with the hidden items view on and still can't figure it out. First time using this operating system.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a hidden file/folder?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107934/how-can-i-make-a-hidden-file-folder)

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> inside your Home folder.

It will displays all the hidden files and folders present inside your Home directory.

```
~/.foldername
```

`~` - **It represents your Home folder.(`/home/$USER`)**

`.foldername` - If a folder name is preceeded by dot `.`, it would hide automatically. You have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to view all the hidden files and folders.

Answer (score 2):

To make that folder all you have to do is type this below, it will create a hidden folder **in your home directory.**

```
    mkdir ~/.foldername
```