# Hide windows 7 partition from Ubuntu 12.04 USB

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, autohide

I am so hopelessly tired of following posts on all forums including this one. I only want my windows 7 partition to be invisible from my Ubuntu 12.04 which I install and run from a USB flash drive. I tried all those fstab posts and nothing works. Everything needs so many commands. Can someone help me to do this task ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a UDEV rule yet? REF: [How to hide a(n) (NTFS) partition from ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu/124124#124124)

Note: `ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"` changes to `ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"` in Ubuntu 12.10, so you'll have to revisit this file when you upgrade from 12.04.

You could also have a shell script that runs `umount /dev/sdb1` (or whatever your hard disk's NTFS partition is, check with `mount | grep ntfs` first), then run that script from Startup Applications so it umounts the partition whenever you login.

Comment: Well, I had done this hiding thing 2 years ago and I only remember it was simple. It was not as complicated in the link which you gave. I think i used pysdm back then. But, some posts say that pysdm is "dangerous" whatever that means.

Comment: @Deen: I used to just set the Hidden partition flag with gparted or similar, but Nautilus (or maybe HAL) just ignores that now.

Comment: In my case, that option made it impossible to boot into windows. I had to reset the hidden partition option to fix that. I don't know why this post has not received more attention yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Disks` for that

Select your drive, and select your windows partition. Then click on little cogs, and choose modify mount option

Uncheck automatic mount, and uncheck 'Visible in GUI'. Save.

[image: Disks changing automatic munt option]