# Hiding partition in Nautilius

Tags: nautilus, 13.10, dell, filesystem, ntfs

I'm using ubuntu 13.10 and nautilus (File) v 3.8.2 on Dell Inspiron 7535 which had comes with windows 8 pre installed. Dell had already created lots of partitions.

I want to make this partitions not to show in the nautilus?

What will be best way to hide this?

NOTE: As of now I want to mess up / delete that partitions as I have already a had a battle  installing ubuntu on this machine.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to hide them in Nautilus only, but the kernel can hide partitions system-wide. Check this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1305383, and this: [How to hide a(n) (NTFS) partition from ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu)