# How can I get all USB storage device to mount as read-only or offer no mount options at all?

Tags: usb, nautilus, mount, usb-drive, read-only

These are the two parts of my query:

- Is there a way to **mount all USB storage/flash/removable storage devices as read-only** i.e. **set the default mount policy to read-only**? Back in Windows OS, I could achieve *write-protection* for USB storage devices with some registry tweaks. How can I do that in Ubuntu?
- Using *dconf-editor* I can control the *automount, automount-open, autorun,... (schema: org.cinnamon.desktop.media-handling)*, but *Nautilus will always allow the devices to be mounted in a single click* ! I don't want that! So can I control mount options that appear in nautilus under the *Devices* menu of sidebar? Or **is there a better way so that only the Root is able to mount such devices**? I tried setting permissions in/to `/dev/bus/usb` with no luck at all.

Answer (score 0):

Most USB flash drives are formatted with FAT32. This is a simple filesystem with no journaling or other fancy features. Data is only written if metadata or file contents get modified unless you set the mount policy to read-only. For Linux distributions, you could do this by adding the `ro` option when manually mounting a partition with the `mount` program.

You are now looking at desktop programs (Nautilus) which does not use `mount` directly (it does not even have permissions to do so). It likely uses [UDisks](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/) instead (actually, udisks2). In the manual page [udisks(8)](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/udisks.8.html) you can find some variables that can be used with udev. To hide a partition from Nautilus for example, have a look at this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/416702/6969).

I am not aware of an option to set the default mount policy, but you can certainly specify a mount option when manually mounting as root:

```
udisksctl mount --options ro ...
```

Changing the permissions of `/dev/bus/XXX/YYY` is nonsense. Normal users are able to mount external storage because there is a privileged daemon running (`udisksd`) that operates on behalf of the user.

Comment: Lekensteyn I actually want what I've asked for in my Q to be the default policy in my system; every new devices attached should follow the rules.. (something similar to setting removable devices mount policy to read-only as done in windows where you simply set this policy and go.. every new devices would then be mounted readonly, no extra work needed to be done by hand..)

Comment: @rusty Unfortunately, that feature is not implemented in udisks. There exists an old patch on https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33461, but not much people seems to be interested. Perhaps you can open a feature request on Launchpad, Martin Pitt is a Ubuntu and Udisks developer so it might get more attention.