# make non-ubuntu drives disappear

Tags: windows, hard-drive, unmount

I am an absolute newbie with Ubuntu. Would be happy if somebody could help me here. I have a windows 8 pc with several internal hard drives. I managed to install Ubuntu 13.10 on one of those drives, by clicking on "something else" during the installation process. I start Ubuntu in the BIOS during boot by pushing F8 (Asus mainboard), which allows me to select the drive from which to boot. (Default is windows 8, which is fine with me).

So here is my question. When in Ubuntu, I can see my other drives. Is there a way to make the drives "disappear"? I mean so that Ubuntu does not even know that they exist? Of course I still need the drives fully funtional on the windows side. Would be great if this would be possible.

Thanks for your help in advance!
mark

Comment: May be this old question from AU will help you, http://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Mark, I had some account issues and had to make a new one. Just add these lines to /etc/crontab.  You must be *COMPLETELY* sure that Ubuntu is installed on that ST3.. drive, otherwise your Ubuntu installation will be broken.

```
@reboot root umount /dev/sda1
@reboot root umount /dev/sdh1
@reboot root umount /dev/sdi1
```

On the bright side..I don't think Ubuntu would allow you to unmount the root partition..but I haven't had the opportunity to test that theory haha.  Please respond if not all of the drives disappear, then we will need to do some further investigation into their partition numbers.

Comment: Hi David, I am 100% sure that Ubuntu is installed on ST3120827AS. I couldn't quite figure out where I should add those lines. Where do I find /etc/crontab? In the Terminal? Sorry, but I'm just getting started with Ubuntu...

Comment: No problem,  Open a terminal and type 'sudo -s' and provide your login password if asked.  Assuming you have an administrator account on the machine, this will change you to the 'root' user which has admin privileges which are needed to edit crontab, a file used to schedule commands.  Then type 'vim /etc/crontab'. This will open up /etc/crontab using vim, a text editor included with Ubuntu.  Then press 'i' to change to -INSERT- mode, you should see INPUT appear at the bottom of the screen.  Copy and paste those @reboot lines from the original post and these will run next time you reboot.

Comment: After pasting, press escape to exit INPUT mode and type :wq and press enter, wq meaning 'write the changes and quit'.

Comment: Hi David, just wanted to get back to you. I attempted your suggestion, but to no avail. In the meantime, I had a chat with a colleague and he suggest I try something else:

Comment: First „sudo blkid“ to list all the partions, 
then „sudo gedit /etc/fstab“,
then "/dev/sda1 none ntfs defaults,noauto 0 0"

Comment: Seems to bring about the result I was looking for. The drives do no longer appear in the file structure.