# Restrict access to windows system files

Tags: lock

I have both Ubuntu and windows 8 in my PC, i just want to make sure that i don't accidentally delete windows files. Is there a way to do so?? Maybe a partition locking tool or anything.

Is there a way to restrict access to windows files by Ubuntu users?

Comment: if you need help with /etc/fstab please edit into your question the result of `more /etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest method: set the partition to mount read-only for any user.

In general is it a bad idea to mount another operating systems core files anyways and just mount a separate partition to store documents for both systems.

Related document:

- [Ubuntu help on mounting windows partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting files with only one operating system installed is no more or less difficult than with two. Just don't do it. Your windows partition will be obvious when you see it. If you really want to be sure then unmount it. You can also have Ubuntu mount it read only.

**I would have a look** [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions)

If you're referring to when installing the second operating system then that's pretty simple as well. The installer will be very clear about how it's installing itself to the drive by giving you a few options. It will ask if you want to share the drive with windows, replace windows or do "something else" which involves manually setting up your partitions but I don't advise you doing that unless you're an experienced user and know what you're doing.

In the end, if you back up your files like we all should be doing then you're fine. Make sure to back up your personal files before installing Ubuntu and then do regular backups weekly. Important things like legal documents, files for work, family pictures, etc. should be backed up when changes are made.

**To learn more about backing up your files, [check this out](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem).**

Make sure to read the Ubuntu wiki section pertaining to installation as well. I would post a link but I don't have enough rep to post more than two.

Cheers!

Comment: Could you add an instruction to do only RO access the Windows drive? I think this is the simplest solution to the question.

Comment: There is already a huge amount of documentation which covers this even right on this site. I would use the search function. With a single Google search for "mount windows drive read only on boot" I found well over 2 million results and the third hit from the top was an article on this site covering, in great detail, how to mount windows partitions in Ubuntu.

Another thing to consider is that the partition will not be mounted  by default and the user must chose to mount it before they can access the files.

Comment: Also consider hiding the partition from Ubuntu entirely. Look here -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu.