# How to disable showing my Windows NTFS partion in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ntfs

i'm dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop and i allocate 4 NTFS partition for Windows and one Ext4 partition for Ubuntu,
when Ubuntu start it show all of my NTFS partition as devices,
i need to prevent all access to my Windows partition inside Ubuntu.

Comment: just dont mount them

Comment: @edwardtorvalds They would appear in the devices list and mouted with a click.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I know, thats why I said just let them appear dont mount them

Comment: avoid mounting ntfs partitions is not a option for me,i need to prevent any access to ntfs partitions,i like to keep each operating system independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were a desktop as opposed to a laptop, and you don't specify, I might advise cloning the partitions to separate hard drives and literally switching off the drive you don't wish accessed.  That's what I'd do.

**UPDATE:  I found the answer *ON THIS SITE***

It is entirely possible to get exactly what you want, but in my opinion it is not remotely easy.  Please see the answer in the following linked question with the most upvotes on it, currently 11 but sure to rise:

[How to hide a(n) (NTFS) partition from ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu)

Comment: Why?  There is no perfect solution.  I pointed to TWO possible solutions, a better one My Own, and one which solves the problem in a possibly more elegant but not necessarily easier way.

Comment: I provided not one but TWO answers, one involving a link.  You may choose to remove all of your commentary, or I shall remove NONE.