# How can I block access to my Windows partition from Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, ntfs

I have a dual boot setup with Ubuntu and Wiindows. I can see Windows partitions from Ubuntu. How can I remove access permission for these partitions?

Comment: Are you meaning you don't want the windows partition to mount when you boot Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you mean file permissions? Please specify what you mean.

Comment: yes dont want windows partition to mount and shown in leftside. not only shown but also remove file permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu) page - this has answers to your question. Additionally you may also try the solution given by *Morbius1* [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1757405)

Comment: please upvote incase you like the solutions :) Thank you

Comment: @ArnabSanyal. If your answer is just a link to another Ask Ubuntu answer on a separate question, you should instead vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the icons from appearing on your desktop if you search for Media options in settings for your distro/desktop. Nothing will be touched on the Windows partitions unless you configure it to, or double click one of those icons which will mount the drive. That is easily un-doable by clicking the eject button I the file manager though.