# Dual boot: File system errors on startup: "RUN fsck MANUALLY" - how to prevent in the future?

Tags: boot, filesystem, ssd, disk, fsck

I've recently had an SSD disk problem after booting Ubuntu 20.04 Linux: [image: a disk problem]

The file system had errors, but fortunately, after running `fsck` the machine is working again. The `fsck` fixed many errors, probably hundreds.

The machine is dual boot, each OS having a separate 1TB SSD drive:

- Microsoft Windows 10
- Linux Ubuntu 20.04

THE PROBLEM HAPPENED AFTER WINDOWS WAS BRIEFLY USED FOR A FEW MINUTES - after the machine was booted again into Linux, it showed the above errors.

What should I do to prevent this in the future:

- Will the OS upgrade be of any help?
- IS the new SSD drive the only way?

Comment: probably you shut down improperly (or the system crashed). Don't do that. You can run a smart test on your SSD to see if it needs to be replaced, but that isn't necessarily the issue.

Comment: No, the system was shut down properly.

Comment: I completely forgot to mention that machine is dual-boot, and that the problem happened after Windows was used for a few minutes, than booted into Linux again.

Answer (score 4):

The error "ENEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY." happens whenever the system detects that the file system is damaged, to the extent that an automatic file check is not anymore possible. It can happen if the system crashes, or if the computer was improperly shutdown, e.g., because of a power outage. That way, the system cannot properly close the open files and update the file system, leaving it in an inconsistent state. If, despite properly shutting down, the problem reappears regularly, then expect a failing drive that may need replacement.

> Will the OS upgrade be of any help?

Not at all. A supported operating system will keep the drive in a healthy condition if the computer does not shut down improperly.

> Is the new SSD drive the only way?

First you need to find the cause of the problem. If the issue reoccurs even if the system was correctly shut down by choosing "Power Off", then start suspecting the drive.

Comment: I completely forgot to mention that machine is dual-boot, and that the problem happened after Windows was used for a few minutes (very rarely used), than booted into Linux again.

Comment: Yes, the system was shut down properly.

Comment: Here is my question about dual-boot 2 years ago when I was setting it up: [Dual boot on two separate disk drives - prevent Linux from accessing Windows disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291787/dual-boot-on-two-separate-disc-drives-prevent-linux-from-accessing-windows-dis) - seems like I foresaw this problem!?