# Can I Unmount My Dualboot Windows Drive?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

Yesterday I successfully dual-booted and installed windows on the part of the SSD in my system. The Windows and Linux parts work well, but the disk partition I have reserved for Windows appears in the Devices part of Linux.

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTEdX.png)

How do I make this partition not appear in Linux? Will Windows files be damaged if I unmount using the GParted?

[GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAUFZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

`Linux` will not damage your `Windows` files or your `Windows` partition if you unmount it. 
If you want to hide it for one session, you can right-click it in your filemanager and choose the option 'hide'. 
See also [How to hide a(n) (NTFS) partition from ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu) and https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1247829.html. You can also watch https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj90u7Jm8b4AhUFxYUKHeY-BaEQtwJ6BAghEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DQ14k1hIw8nw&usg=AOvVaw2YSu_c_GUT2M8Q639ChGtc on Youtube ( hiding unmounted partitions .

Answer (score 0):

You can unmount it using `umount` itself or GParted or other tools.

But, If don't need your Windows partition and you want to make it gone, you can remove the corresponding line from your `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: My Windows-partition and my other NTFS partition ( I keep my documents, photos, music and videos etc. seperate from y OSes ) are not mentioned in my fstab and neither is my Mint partition. So there I cannot uncomment them.