# How to hide files with certain extensions?

Tags: nautilus

I have plenty of files in a folder with extension of .dep, I want to hide these files. But I don't want to change their names such as adding a dot ahead of them. 
What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a file in that folder called ".hidden" and put any filenames you want to hide in there.  I don't believe it supports wildcards, but you can use a script to add the filenames every so often:

See this answer: 
[How can I hide directories without changing their names?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2034/how-can-i-hide-directories-without-changing-their-names)

Answer (score 4):

```
ls *.<ext> >> .hidden
```

Simple as that