# Hide FIles in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gnome, nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I hide directories without changing their names?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2034/how-can-i-hide-directories-without-changing-their-names)

I would like to ask, if it's possible to hide files from nautilus without adding a dot at the beginning of the file/folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you have to create a file called `.hidden` in the same directory where you have the files you want to hide.

Then all you have to do is to open that file with a Text Editor and add the names of files to that file, one per line (You can also **hide directories** with the same method). Then you need to refresh the view.

Also I have made a script for this propose:

[source](https://github.com/mackatozis/uni/blob/master/OS/Operating%20Systems/hide-files.sh)

To see your hidden files press **Ctrl+H**